# Method to ask for input until condition is met and return this input

Tags: java, exception

I have a problem writing method in Java which ask for letter until user actually types a letter. Then I want my method to return this letter.

So, if user types "2" I want my method to ask for a letter again.

I tried writing code below, but letter is created inside loop, so I can't return it outside the loop.

```
public String askForLetter() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int flag = 1;
    do {
        System.out.println("Type a letter");
        String letter = in.next();
        if (isLetter(letter)) {
            flag = 2;
            return letter;
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument, try again");
    } while (flag == 1)
    return letter;
}
```

How to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: Declare it whit a default value (can be "") before the loop and assign the input value inside the loop.

Comment: so if i can understand the program should not exit until the user enter a letter?

Comment: As it is, there will only be one iteration of your loop : either it is a success and it returns a value, or it is a failure and it throws an `Exception` . The `while` condition will never be evaluated .

Comment: Yes, program should not exit until user enter a letter

Comment: I also tried declaring letter value before the loop but IDE says "unreachable statement"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here, but fortunately they're all very easily solved.

First off, you want the loop to continue until you get valid input. Throwing an exception is a great way to *not* continue the normal path of execution, so nix the exception throwing; it's not needed here.

You also don't need to `return letter` inside the loop. It's not actually hurting anything, but it does make the outer `return` redundant. So, for the sake of readability and good design, it would be ideal to remove that as well.

Finally, your main concern regarding the fact that the variable is defined inside the loop is dealing with an issue called variable scope. A variable's scope is (roughly) the smallest brace-enclosed block to which it belongs. So if you want access to it outside the loop, declare it outside the loop and assign it a default value.

```
public String askForLetter() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int flag = 1;
    String letter = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Type a letter");
        letter = in.next();
        if (isLetter(letter)) {
            flag = 2;
        }
    } while (flag == 1)
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: Please add braces to your if statement, as omitted braces often lead to bugs if the code is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not terribly late, but might I propose simpler answer? It's the same as Silvio's method, but I took out the unnecessary check in the middle.

```
public String askForLetter() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("Type a letter");
        letter = in.next();
    } while(!isLetter(letter));     // perform the check for the letter here

    in.close();                     // close the Scanner since we hate warnings
    return letter;
}
```

Since we already have a conditional in the do-while, we can simply check the letter itself rather than changing the state of a flag. Plus, as Silvio said, we want this to be as simple and as readable as possible.